# Complex Analysis: Liouville's theorem Proof

Tags: complex-analysis, alternative-proof

I'm being asked to find an alternate proof for the one commonly given for Liouville's Theorem in complex analysis by evaluating the following given an entire function $f$, and two distinct, arbitrary complex numbers $a$ and $b$:
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint_{|z|=R} {f(z)\over(z-a)(z-b)} dz $$

What I've done so far is I've tried to apply the cauchy integral formula, since there are two singularities in the integrand, which will fall in the contour for $R$ approaches infinity.  So I got:

$$2{\pi}i\biggl({f(a)\over a-b}+{f(b)\over b-a}\biggr)$$

Which equals
$$2{\pi}i\biggl({f(a)-f(b)\over a-b}\biggr)$$

and I got stuck here I don't quite see how I can get from this, plus $f(z)$ being bounded and analytic, that can tell me that $f(z)$ is a constant function.  Ugh, the more well known proof is so much simpler -.-
Any suggestions/hints?  Am I at least on the right track?

Comment: Your choice of $a$ and $b$ was arbitrary --- if you can show that $f(a)-f(b) = 0$, you're done.  So how can you argue that your expressions are all equal to zero?

Comment: I noticed that what you said would prove it but I'm really not sure how I would go about arguing it.  Any theorems/lemmas I should go review?  I've looked into using cauchy integral theorem, ML formula, and Cauchy Estimates.  Whenever I try using Cauchy estimates, I can't help but just end up with the normal proof of Liouville (as seen on proofwiki, wikipedia, etc.).  Are one of those what I ought to be using or am I completely overlooking something important?

Comment: How do you know that f(z) is of power one? Don't you just know that f(z) is entire? We don't know specifically what f(z) is. Couldn't it have a power greater than that of the denominator, so the denominator wouldn't dominate?

Comment: One of the hypotheses of Liouville's theorem is that f(z) is bounded, as well as entire.  Sorry I didn't state that in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the $ML$ inequality (with boundedness of $f$) to show $\displaystyle \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \oint_{|z|=R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz = 0$.

Combining this with your formula using the Cauchy integral formula, you get $$ 0 = 2\pi i\bigg(\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\bigg)$$ from which you immediately conclude $f(b) = f(a)$.  Since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary, this means $f$ is constant.

Comment: I've never heard it called "the ML inequality". What does that stand for - "**Maximum** of function times **Length** of contour," perhaps?

Comment: @Gerry:  Exactly.  I don't remember where I read it.  A quick google search shows it's not an uncommon thing to call it.  What do you call it?

Comment: I don't quite understand this method.  Wouldn't the L in this case be approaching infinity since the contour is |z|=R?  How would you use ML?  How would you use ML in this case?

Comment: I never had a name for it, Jason, I just use it. calvin, yes, $L$ goes to infinity, but you know, sometimes if $x\to\infty$ and $y\to0$ you can find out what $xy$ does by seeing how *fast* $x\to\infty$ and $y\to0$.

Comment: ahh, I see. is it because f(z) is always finite, but the (z-a)(z-b) is gonna put an R^2 on the bottom no matter what, So the ML is gonna have a first power of R in the numerator, and an R^2 in the denominator, and so it's all controlled by the R^2, making the ML approach zero (all stated informally, of course.

Comment: I've certainly heard that term before.

Comment: @calvin:  Exactly as you said.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, but the $ML$ inequality only works in one direction - to show that $\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz \leq 0$. In order to have it actually equal $0$, you need to be able to show the inequality in the opposite direction, don't you? If so, how would you do this?

Comment: @JessyCat:  The $ML$ inequality applies to $\left|\int_{|z|=R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}\; dz\right|$, not to $\int_{|z|=R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}\; dz$.  (In fact, without the absolute value bars, the integral is (potentially) a complex number.  What does it mean for a complex number to be $\leq 0$?)

Comment: @JasonDeVito, its modulus must be $\leq 0$, but a modulus cannot be negative, so it must be $0$. I see...

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint_{|z|=R} {f(z)\over(z-a)(z-b)} \; dz=2{\pi}i\biggl({f(a)-f(b)\over a-b}\biggr) \to 2\pi if'(b)\text{ as }a\to b.$$

If one could somehow use boundedness of $f$ to show that
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint_{|z|=R} {f(z)\over(z-a)(z-b)} \;dz \to 0\text{ as }a\to b,
$$
then one would have shown that $f'(b)=0$.  Since $b$ was arbitrary, one would have  $f'=0$ everywhere.

Comment: To put it another way: calvin, you have *evaluated* the integral; now *estimate* the integral.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, no. Actually, $b$ is not completely arbitrary, $a \neq b$, so you have to show that $f(a)=f(b)$. I would have liked to have seen more steps in the solution above where they showed that, though.